# how can i call two dictionaries in files?

Tags: python

from collections import OrderedDict
import json

def read_classification_from_file(dict_file1,dict_file2):
    with open(dict_file1,'r') as f:
        dict1 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    with open(dict_file2,'r') as f:
        data2 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

```
# Creates list of lists pairing each value in 
# dict1 with each value in dict2
return [[value1,value2] 
        for value1 in dict1.values() 
        for value2 in dict2.values()]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your post? It's not at all clear what you want to do.

Comment: the first function works when you provide the truth_dict and pred_dict dictionaries  so i want to use in a different way by opening example1.txt and example2.txt in read_classification_from_file(): and then i want compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False): to use the returned dictionaries in  read_classification_from_file():

Comment: or if i can open both files in compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False): it will be better if its possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, and if I have understood you correctly then the ideal way to accomplish what you are trying to do but would be to take a different approach, but you want to stick with this approach, you can use the eval() function. You read in the the strings from your .txt files, but to use that string you need to pass it as an argument to the eval() function for it to be parsed and evaluated as a Python expression:

```
with open('example1.txt') as f:
    call = f.readline()

truth_dict = eval(call)
```

So this might work:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def compute_confusion_matrix(file1, file2, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False):
    TP=0
    FP=0
    TN=0
    FN=0
    with open(file1) as f:
        call = f.readline()
        truth_dict = eval(call)
    with open(file2) as f:
        call - f.readline()
        pred_dict = eval(call)

    for key,value in truth_dict.items():
        if truth_dict[key]==pred_dict[key] == neg_tag:
            TP +=1
        if pred_dict[key]==truth_dict[key] == pos_tag:
            FP +=1
        if truth_dict[key]==pred_dict[key] != neg_tag :
            TN +=1
        if truth_dict[key]==pred_dict[key] != pos_tag:
            FN +=1
    ConfMat = namedtuple('ConfMat', 'tp tn fp fn')

    p=ConfMat(TP, FP, TN, FN)
    return p
```

Comment: can i open two dictionaries in compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False): with out using read_classification_from_file():???

Comment: You aren't "opening a dictionary" from the .txt file. You are reading in strings, NOT dictionaries. You need to make them into dictionaries, and by using the eval function, you can treat these strings like Python expressions and create a dictionary like you would in your "test". Otherwise, all you have are strings.

Comment: ok but the .txt files are already dictionaries so all what i want to read them in compute_confusion_matrix so i can test the functions by printing

Comment: The .txt files are NOT dictionaries. They are STRINGS. To save an object in a file you need to use object serialization with the 'pickle' module: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: sorry yes just now i realized it thanks but could you read the two .txt files in compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False) and print it by providing the .txt files in the parameters

Comment: can you edit my post of the function compute_confusion_matrix(truth_dict, pred_dict, pos_tag=True, neg_tag=False) that way

Comment: @jack you could load the dictionaries from the file using [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#basic-usage)

Comment: Yeah, that might be the best approach, JCVanHamme.

Comment: i tried but when i try to print the function and changing the parameter as .txt it was saying error truth_dict its not defind

Comment: can someone please edit my post function so i can i understand my mistake

Comment: I think you are still confused. What do you mean you tried to print the function and changing the parameter as .txt? That doesn't make any sense. What exactly did you change?

Comment: i want to print any .txt not only 'example1.txt'

Comment: i meant print like this print(compute_confusion_matrix('example1.txt', 'example2.txt', pos_tag='SPAM', neg_tag='OK'))

Comment: i want the function to expect any .txt file

Comment: 'example1.txt' is just a string. If you pass it to your function, it's understood as a string, not as a .txt file. You can use what I showed you outside your function given that you know the name of the file.

Comment: you can see how the testing compute_confusion_matrics above in my post worked well but i want test my function this way print(compute_confusion_matrix('example1.txt', 'example2.txt', pos_tag='SPAM', neg_tag='OK'))

Comment: its failing when the .txt contains a string ,maybe i did understand the question in my book in a wrong i updated the question in my book

Answer (score 0):

Use json if your data is being created by or shared with other sources (use only double quotes!). May want to use OrderedDict to ensure proper order, or better yet, re-organize your data to be a simple list of values, since the keys don't appear to be all that important:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

def read_classification_from_file(dict_file1,dict_file2):
    with open(dict_file1,'r') as f:
        dict1 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    with open(dict_file2,'r') as f:
        data2 = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

    # Creates list of lists pairing each value in 
    # dict1 with each value in dict2
    return [[value1,value2] 
            for value1 in dict1.values() 
            for value2 in dict2.values()]
```